# User Account Control (UAC) in Windows 7 Does Not Prompt for Fingerprint Authentication

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, administrator, uac, biometrics

I login with domain credentials (I'm in an enterprise-setting) as a standard user on a Windows 7 box. I logon with my fingerprint just fine, and even have fingerprints saved on a local administrative account, which works just fine. When I need to elevate my privileges UAC prompts me for Admin credentials. It does not, however, provide me with the ability to scan using my fingerprint, it only displays username and password fields. UAC never allows me the option to authenticate with my fingerprint(s). I've looked in group policy and enabled everything there, double-checked settings in Biometric devices in Control Panel, but cannot find anything that changes how UAC behaves. I have heard from several domain admins that they ran into this before they moved to Windows 8.1, but they don't remember much about the issue or how it was resolved. I'm sure Windows 8.1 would solve it but I'm hoping I can find a solution short of "upgrade your OS." Any of you Superusers have a suggestion?

Comment: Can you give some more details on your hardware?

Comment: Lenovo Thinkcentre m83 with Lenovo fingerprint reader. 

Thinkvantage Fingerprint Software with AuthenTec TouchChip Fingerprint Coprocessor (WBF advanced mode).